# Insert picture to Excel VBA, method Pictures failed

Tags: excel, vba, insert, image

Tried to make a macro that progressively inserts 3 images in Excel

One worksheet (pics) contains the URLs of images in Column A row 1-3

The other worksheet (outputs) is supposed to output the images horizontally.

```
Sub testinsertpix()
Dim i As Integer
Dim link As String

For i = 1 To 3
link = Worksheets("pics").Cells(i, "A").Value
Cells(1, i).Select
ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert (link)

Next i

End Sub
```

It does insert the first image, but fails when the loop reaches the 2nd picture.

"Insert method of Pictures class failed"

Little help please?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Dim link as Variant
```

Then output the value and see where it's going wrong. My best guess is your URL isn't being read the way you'd expect.

Comment: The URL is being read fine. I put in a line Msgbox "link" just after the loop to check already. Excel status bar also does show it downloading the picture, but it just gives me this fail error message.

Comment: And you're 100% sure that there aren't any extra spaces at the end or the beginning, stuff like that? I've seen everything reading cell values in vba...

Answer (score -1):

I have a similar macro and I had the same error.
For me this helped: `On error resume next`

```
Sub INSERTPICTURES()
With Sheets("Condition_report")
    Dim cella As Range

    For Each cella In .Range("A1:A10000").Cells

        If cella.Interior.ColorIndex = 3 Then

        ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture Filename:=cella, LinkToFile:=msoFalse, SaveWithDocument:=msoCTrue, Left:=cella.MergeArea.Left, Top:=cella.MergeArea.Top, Width:=cella.MergeArea.Width - 3, Height:=cella.MergeArea.Height
        On Error Resume Next

        End If
    Next
End With
End Sub
```