# Link is in a case,when I Click one button, image(corresponding with the link) goes directly in a Area

Tags: excel, vba

I have a link in the Case of BC3, and when I click over one Button, I want that the image(corresponding with the link) goes directly and automatically in the Area (R19:U30).

```
Worksheets("CalculInfo").Range("BC3").Value = ChoixImage

 image = ChoixImage



    Dim r As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim imagePath As String
Dim img As Picture

Set ws = Worksheets("PDF")
Set r = ws.Range("R19:U30")

'I got an error here "Impossible to read the image picture propriety insert of the class picture"

Set img = ws.Pictures.Insert(image)



With img
    .ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
    .Top = r.Top
    .Left = r.Left
    .Width = r.Width
    .Height = r.Height
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this and revise the line

```
Set img = ws.Pictures.Insert(strImage)
```

to

```
Dim strImage as String
strImage = Worksheets("CalculInfo").Range("BC3").Value2
ws.Pictures.Insert(strImage)
```

Comment: Dear, The link in "BC3" will change all the time, I need a variable.

Comment: @Chris: Just make sure that the "link" in BC3 is a full path including the file name and extension.

Comment: Dear, Is it all right ?? C:\Users\gaetan.affolter\Desktop\test.jpg

Comment: ws.Pictures.Insert (strImage)--> Error "methode Insert Class Picture failed"

Comment: Is the sheet protected? Maybe you need to add `Worksheets("CalculInfo").Unprotect "yourPassword"`?

Comment: Alternatively, you can also try `ws.Pictures.Insert strImage` instead of `ws.Pictures.Insert(strImage)`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21103545/vba-syntax-for-pictures-insert-incorrect-insert-method-of-picture-class-fail
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16581775/insert-picture-to-excel-vba-method-pictures-failed